Is Dispel Magic Limited to only Spells?
What it was
Before diving into this, I want to clarify that I am addressing this question specifically to the 2024 ruleset. In 2014, there was much debate and ambiguity, in my opinion, about how this was to be ruled. However, this Sage Advice on page 16 provided specific examples of how it did and did not work and cleared up the ambiguity.
2024 ushered in specific definitions.
The 2024 Players Handbook provides the following Dispel Magic description (emphasis mine):

Choose one creature, object, or magical effect within range. Any ongoing spell of level 3 or lower on the target ends. For each ongoing spell of level 4 or higher on the target, make an ability check using your spellcasting ability (DC 10 plus that spell's level). On a successful check, the spell ends.
Using a Higher-Level Spell Slot. You automatically end a spell on the target if the spell's level is equal to or less than the level of the spell slot you use.

The second and third sentences of the spell description mention how to resolve specific spell levels, but I am not quite convinced that just because those sentences are present, that the spell is limited strictly to that resolution.
The glossary of the Player's Handbook defines Magical Effect as:

An effect is magical if it is created by a spell,  a magic item, or a phenomenon that a rule labels as magical.

Example
The College of Glamour Bard has Beguiling Magic, which, if the circumstances are right, forces a creature to make a Wisdom Saving throw or be Charmed or Frightened. It is not a spell, but it certainly seems magical.
Would Dispel Magic dispel this effect or something similar that specifically is NOT a spell?  I suppose another way to ask this is, did Dispel Magic have its effect expanded by virtue of the definition of Magical Effect as written in the glossary?

Related question in 2014: What happens when you target a "magical effect" with Dispel Magic?

However, this Sage Advice [...] cleared up the ambiguity - really?

It ends only spells
The text is actually pretty straightforward:

Choose one creature, object, or magical effect within range. Any ongoing spell of level 3 or lower on the target ends

The creature, object or magical effect is not what ends - it is the target of Dispel Magic. Spells on that target end.

This includes spells that are "on" the target because they are creating the target in the case of spells that create magical effects. For example, if you cast Fog Cloud, the magical fog is not on an object or creature or on another magical effect, and if that were not the case, you could not dispel it, but you can.
We have rules evidence that Dispel Magic can dispel stand-alone magical effects that are caused by a spell: for example, the spells Antimagic Field and Forcecage create magical effects. Antimagic Field says that Dispel Magic has no effect on the field, and Forcecage says that Dispel Magic cannot dispel it. Both these effects are not on another magical effect, they are just part of the spell's effect. These sentences creating exceptions would not be necessary, if Dispel Magic could only target but not dispel a stand-alone magical effect.
In addition, rules for specific game features can create exceptions following the Specific beats General principle by stating that Dispel Magic works to end or dispel them, even if the effect is not caused by a spell. One such example are the illusions created by a Deck of Illusions.
Lastly, of course the DM rule differently than what the rules say, if they think it creates a more fun game (see this answer for more on that).

A simple case of the spell telling you what it does. I moved the emphasis to that part of the quote. Feel free to change it back, I just wasn’t sure why the previous sentence was emphasized, but emphasizing the actual effect of the spell made sense to me.

A handy mnemonic to remember what Dispel Magic does: it's a "De-spell" effect. Of course, the name of a spell itself does not dictate how a spell works in general, I just mean to say, it's useful for me to remember that Dispel Magic only works on spells. Out of curiosity, I looked it up now, the word "dispel" doesn't actually come from the word "spell", but »From Middle English dispelen, from Latin dispellere (“to disperse; to dispel”).«, dispello »From dis- +‎ pellō (“push, drive”).«

@Thomas, would an antimagic field prevent the Glamour Bard example I gave?

Or….does Dispel Magic work against a beholders eye rays?

@Bryan The description of am field is much more broad than dispel: “No one can cast spells, take Magic actions, or create other magical effects inside the aura, and those things can’t target or otherwise affect anything inside it.” Dispel magic works only on spells because that’s the only thing it says it does. Antimagic field works on all magical effects, because it says it does. Different descriptions, different effects.

(English is not my native language) Could you clarify the parenthetical? Isn't it a big stretch to say that the spell Fog Cloud is "on" the resulting cloud? I do agree that the fog cloud must be dispelable, but I would have thought that the spell being "on" an object has to mean either the object is the spell's target, or somewhat directly affected by it. Isn't the more straightforward interpretation just that Dispel Magic is badly written?

@J.E I‘m neither a native speaker, and agree I think normally on would mean not the thing itself — that is why I have the parenthetical. I think that interpretation doesn‘t work well, as you then could not dispel any spells with "standalone" magical effects. I think it makes more sense to treat those as "on" themselves, even if that is awkward.

@J.E I also think the parenthetical feels a bit odd, to be honest. If you target a magical effect (like Fog Cloud), you dispel that effect (Fog Cloud). Dispel Magic works exactly the same as its 2014 version. Personally, the text in parentheses is confusing.

@Tarod The issue is that dispel magic does not say it dispels the effect it targets, it says it ends ongoing spells on the effect. To be clean, it would need to also say it dispels the targeted effect if it is caused by a spell.

Yeah, maybe. Anyway, if that text is clear for everybody, I'm happy with that. I just wanted to leave my thoughts here :) Thanks for your answer!

So, does it mean that if a creature has a natural magical ability that others in the vicinity have to make a saving throw every round and get Charmed if they fail it, if Dispel Magic is used, then that creature's ability is not dispelled, just the Charming effect is removed from the victim, but then the victim can get charmed again the next round, and a new Dispel Magic is needed to remove that again?

Vsz If the charm is mot caused by a spell, it is not dispelled (unless the creatures ability makes an exception and says so). Only magical effects that are the result of a spell should be dispelled

Re "Spells on that target end.", So you're saying that if you target a magical effect, it dispels the spell on the magic effect? What's an example of a spell on a magic effect?

@ikegami I am not saying "Spells on the target end", dispel magic is saying that. I am saying that if the effect it is caused by a spell, you should treat that effect as if it was "on" the effect, as most spells that just create an effect, like fog cloud, otherwise can not be dispelled

You did not answer my question. Dispel Magic says you can target a magical effect. You say that Dispel Magic says it only dispells spells on targets. That presumes the possibility of the existence of spells on magic effects. What's an example of a spell on a magic effect?

@ikegami An example would be to cast light on an object that also is a magical effect, such as a Minor Creation trinket from prestidigitation.

Fair, but object is already allowed as a target. Let me rephrase. What's an example of a spell on a non-creature, non-object magic effect?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Yes, but...
The spell text says what effect a spell has, and the only effect mentioned in the spell text is to end spells. So by a strict RAW ruling, you are limited to spells only.
However, I think it's more than reasonable for a DM to allow the spell to end other magical effects that are roughly equal in power. It makes sense to me that the game's spell list is not an exhaustive list of everything that's possible with magic in-universe. It also makes sense to me that magical effects that are not from a spell in the spell list would still adhere to the same laws of magic as spells in the spell list. Someone else could of course say that spells and magical effects are two separate things in-universe, so this is just my personal opinion.
This is somewhat supported by the rules, as the 2024 DMG says this about traps' duration (emphasis mine):

Some traps have durations expressed in rounds, minutes, or hours. Others specify that their effects last until the trap is destroyed or dispelled.

It does not mention the spell Dispel Magic explicitly, but I do not know of any other ways to dispel magical effects.

The DM will be put in the unenviable position on ruling on a lot of unsaid things that could affect play significantly. Such as what effective spell level a specific use of Beguiling Magic is. Do you have any experience with using this interpretation and seeing how it works in practice?

This answer is good and doesn't deserve downvotes. Many official D&D adventures use Dispel Magic not only to remove spells but also to neutralize various magical effects. For example, the spell is mentioned in the 2014 Dungeon Master's Guide in the section about how Disabling Traps (DMG pp. 120-121) and again in the new 2024 DMG on Parts of a Trap. Feel free to use this information if you'd like, Joakim.

Yes, this is a useful counterpoint.  The 2024 DMG has instances where Dispel Magic affects other phenomena, such as the Deck of Illusions.  It is not unreasonable for a DM to consider that the few examples in the DMG are exhaustive.  The books can't cover every possible circumstance.

@NeilSlater: I read this answer as a straightforward application of rule zero. If the DM wants to allow "off label" uses of a spell in a specific context, then that is their prerogative as DM. I think it would help if the answer specifically called out some things that the DM ought to consider before doing that (especially with regards to game balance and preventing "cheese"), and some discussion of actual experience would also make the answer better, but just acknowledging that rule zero exists should not require those elements.

@Kevin yes I agree. When I commented the answer was shorter. My suggestion was to expand in a "good subjective" way with backup from experience. But adding the trap example works too

@NeilSlater I'm having a hard time coming up with anything to add from experience other than "this is how my group does it and it works for us".

Even that might be good. It turns a "I believe it will be OK" into "I've seen this work OK". But now you have the trap reference, and that's already enough IMO. I'm only leaving my first comment because someone else referenced it. Hopefully someone will come past later on and clean up
